# Pass file argument through to child make

Tags: makefile

Conditions:

- a makefile is passed to the make: `make -f ../makefile hi`
- the `hi` target also calls `make`

I need a way to propagate the value from `-f` to the sub-make command running inside `hi`.

```
bye: 
    echo 'whatever'

hi:
    ${MAKE} bye
```

Comment: So instead of hard-coding "hi" you would like to pass on whatever was passed in from the command line?  But then if the Make target says what to execute, `hi` already knows it's executing `hi`; how could it not be?  Maybe you could clarify with what you currently get, and what you would like to get instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no default makefile in the current directory
(presumably the reason you are passing `-f ../makefile`) then
your example `../makefile` will work as it is if you invoke
`make` like:

```
$ make MAKEFILES=../makefile hi
make bye
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap'
echo 'whatever'
whatever
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/scrap'
```

See [3.4 The Variable MAKEFILES](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKEFILES-Variable.html)

If there *is* a default makefile in the current directory then this
approach will cause `make` to read the default makefile after it has
read `../makefile`, with untoward results. In that case prefer @Dummy00001's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility I'm aware of is to use the [`MAKEFILE_LIST`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-_0028list-of-parsed-makefiles_0029) variable:

```
CURR_MAKEFILE:=$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

bye: 
    echo 'whatever'

hi:
    +$(MAKE) -f $(CURR_MAKEFILE) bye
```

But note, as it is written in the official documentation, that the variable records all parsed makefiles, including the `include`ed ones. The value of the variable is only reliable when queried at the very top of the makefile, before any includes.